# JavaScript filter JSON objects using HTML forms

Tags: javascript, html, json, forms, filter

I'm looking to filter a list of objects in a JSON array when an HTML checkbox is clicked.  I know about the JavaScript array.sort() method but how do I eliminate items based on checkbox clicks?  Do I need an event listener?

My JSON looks as so:

```
{ "lots" : [
    {
    "name" : "Parking Lot Name",
    "price" : 2,
    "cash" : true,
    "credit" : false,
    "address" : "1234 W Main Ave",
    "center" : {
        "lat" : 67.659414,
        "lng" : -137.414730
    }... etc.
```

So if I've got a form that includes checkboxes for eliminating parking lots based on payment type, how should I go about implementing that?  I've read about a jQuery array.grep() function, is that it?

My page is being built using a JS loop like this:

```
makeList(){
var self = this;

self.jsonFile = $.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'assets/data/default.json',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(response) {
   console.log(response);
 }
});

self.jsonFile.done(function(data){
  //Sort low to high by default
  data.lots.sort(function(a, b){
    return(a.price > b.price)
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < data.lots.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('jsonList').innerHTML +=
      '<li>
        <div id="text">
          <p class="price"> 
            $' + data.lots[i].price +  '.00
          </p>
          <p class="info">' +
            data.lots[i].address +
         '</p>
        </div>
        <form method="get">
          <button type="submit" formaction="https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Current+Location/' +
           data.lots[i].address +
           '">Directions
          </button>
          <button type="submit" formaction="detail-view.html">Details
          </button>
        </form>
      </li>';
  }
});
```

}

Comment: 1. JSON is a method of serializing objects via strings. You don't have JSON, you have an object. 2. What is your question? What is your input, what is your required output, and what triggers the processing?

Comment: You seem to have many syntax errors in your code. Strings can't be broken over multiple lines as in the OP. Are you trying to get objects from the *lots* array that have either "cash" or "credit" as true? Seems to me *reduce* or *filter* will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate like this:
You have to bind a onchange function to checkboxes then use following way to that function

```
  data = [{
      "name": "name",
      "location1": "no",
      "description": "description of services"
      },
     {
      "name": "name2",
      "location1": "yes",

      "description": "description of services2"
       },
       {
        "name": "name3",
         "location1": "no",

        "description": "description of services3"
    }
  ];

   b = $.grep(data, function(el, i) {
     return el.location1.toLowerCase() === "yes" 
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the lots where the payment type is say "cash" using:

```
var cashLots = data.lots.filter(function(lot){return lot.cash});
```

as an arrow function:

```
var cashLots = data.lots.filter(lot => lot.cash);
```